# Could morphia support allowDiskUse?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

In our development with morphia, we met the following errors:

> MongoDB : Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes

According the guide: http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-sort-exceeded-memory-limit-of-104857600-bytes/, the operation 'allow disk use' was the solution.

My questions :

> 1. If morphia supports allowDiskUse operation, if it is possible to show some sample codes?
> 2. If morphia not  #supports this operation, If it is possible to add 'allowDiskUse' from command line as configurations and all aggregations could use 'allowDiskUse' condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this problem. The solution is simply to enable this feature using your AggregatonOptions like this:

```
AggregationOptions options = AggregationOptions.builder()
            // Possibly more stuff here...
            .allowDiskUse(true) // That's it.
            .build();
```

Then aggregate it like this:

```
aggregation.aggregate(MyClass.class, options);
```

Comment: you're right. Morphia has already supported it, others may have a look about the source code. https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/917#issuecomment-218332392